# Vuejs how to add customer chat for facebook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to add `Facebook` chat for my vuejs app. For that, I found a plugin [vue-fb-customer-chat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fb-customer-chat)

In my **Home.vue**
I import and register component and then called inside template like this

```
<VueFbCustomerChat
          page_id="908908908"
          theme_color="#333333"
          locale="en_US"
        ></VueFbCustomerChat>
```

When I run this I got an error

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined
```

I figure out that this is because this pluggin need `https` to run.
So I build and deploy to the prod server. Now that error has gone. But nothing is display in the UI.

But in the demo of that libray it works https://dmnwebdesign.github.io/vue-fb-customer-chat/
How do I achive this with Vuejs?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added this content in your main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFbCustomerChat from 'vue-fb-customer-chat'
 
Vue.use(VueFbCustomerChat)
```

Comment: Any reason to add that? I already imported locally to the component.

Comment: can you attach the full code of the component so that I ll be able to point out the exact problem